# Getting the first visible group in ListView does not work properly

Tags: listview, uwp

I have created a sample app where I have a grouped ListView and while scrolling through the listview I want to get the top visible group in the UI (first visible group). But when I keep scrolling on a touch based device, it starts showing the next group (next to the top visible group) for as long as I keep my finger on the device. If I remove my fingers, it would correct the value. 
Here is my sample app: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=91B2B9D9EA21A110!615&authkey=!AKJV0b_q7g-YZF4&ithint=file%2czip

Code from sample:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ViewModel MyVM = new ViewModel();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            lv.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                ScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChildren<ScrollViewer>(lv).FirstOrDefault();
                if (sv != null)
                {
                    sv.ViewChanged += (ss, ee) =>
                    {
                        IEnumerable<TextBlock> tblocks = FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(lv).Where(x => x.Name == "tbHeader");
                        if (tblocks != null)
                        {
                            foreach (TextBlock tblock in tblocks)
                            {
                                if (IsVisibileToUser(tblock, sv))
                                {
                                    first.Text = tblock.Text;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsVisibileToUser(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
        {
            if (element == null || container == null)
                return false;

            if (element.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
                return false;

            Rect elementBounds = element.TransformToVisual(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
            Rect containerBounds = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);

            return (elementBounds.Top < containerBounds.Bottom && elementBounds.Bottom > containerBounds.Top);
        }
    }

public class ClassA
    {
        public DateTime DateTimePropertyOfClassA { get; set; }
    }

public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            //return a grouped collection:
            Grouped = from x in CollectionOfClassA group x by x.DateTimePropertyOfClassA into grp orderby grp.Key select grp;
        }

        public IList<ClassA> CollectionOfClassA { get; set; } = new List<ClassA>()
        {
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-04-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-05-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-06-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA =DateTime.Parse("2016-07-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-09-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-12-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA =DateTime.Parse("2016-06-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA =DateTime.Parse("2016-06-01")}
        };

        public IEnumerable<object> Grouped { get; }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs"
                      IsSourceGrouped="True"
                      Source="{x:Bind MyVM.Grouped, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="first" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="12"></TextBlock>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbHeader" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Is there anything I can do to improve this functionality?

Comment: Consider adding some code snippet instead of a link to download your sample app, This would encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ScrollViewer.ViewChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged.aspx) will be fired several times during scrolling, we can't control how many times the `IsVisibileToUser` method be called in your code.

`Rect elementBounds` will be dynamically changed during scrolling, here is a workaround you can try: reducing the region in the `ScrollViewer` to only one `TextBlock`'s size, for example:

```
private bool IsVisibileToUser(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
    if (element == null || container == null)
        return false;

    if (element.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
        return false;

    Rect elementBounds = element.TransformToVisual(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    Rect containerBounds = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);

    return (elementBounds.Top <= element.ActualHeight && elementBounds.Bottom > containerBounds.Top);
}
```

Comment: I actually posted wrong code. I had return (elementBounds.Top < containerBounds.Bottom && elementBounds.Bottom > containerBounds.Top); and it was still having the same issue. The problem is when the very next group is being scrolled into view, the textblock which is still at top will return false from IsVisibleToUser because it fails the condition 'elementBounds.Bottom > containerBounds.Top' since elementBounds.Bottom is negative and containerBounds.Top is 0

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, I know, I tested your posted sample, not your posted code. Please notice that I changed return condition to `return (elementBounds.Top <= element.ActualHeight && elementBounds.Bottom > containerBounds.Top);`, I only changed this code.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, How is that going on? Have you tested my code? Any other problem?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I just tested and it works perfectly fine in my sample application. I would just go ahead and integrate it in my actual project and see if it works there as well. I will update you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I am facing one issue with this code where if I have a very long list (suppose if I modify the code in ViewModel class to have the CollectionOfClassA populated with many groups to have enough of them to do a flick scrolling i.e. tap and scroll once and remove the finger and let it scroll with the inertia). It is not updating the top visible item properly. It happens specially when I scroll up to view the items in the beginning of the list. It almost works fine when I scroll down to view the items in the end. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, It's better to ask a new question here, maybe with a sample code and problem image, actually I do not quite clearly understand this problem, do you mean it works for scrolling down but not works for scrolling up?

Comment: I will post a new question and post the link here Grace. Thanks.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453039/first-visible-group-in-the-listview-uwp

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, OK, I'm now working on another case, I will look into this later, of course communities will also offer help. If I have an answer for this question, I will post there.