# UWP Access main header group in listview

Tags: c#, listview, header, uwp

In UWP, I need to get current group's info, from listview.

My groups are defined as:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="GroupsList" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
<ListView x:Name="LvPeople" ItemsSource="{x:Bind GroupsList.View}"/>
```

What's the property that holds the information of current visible group?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, I think what you actually want is to get the first visible group header information. AFAIK, currently there is no property for directly get the current first visible header. If you do want this feature, you may need to use [`Visual​Tree​Helper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) get the elements inside group header and try to calculate if it is visible, but this may not be recommended. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853167/getting-the-first-visible-group-in-listview-does-not-work-properly) is a similar thread you can reference. The following method can help you judge if it is visible.

```
private bool IsVisibileToUser(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
   if (element == null || container == null)
       return false;

   if (element.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
       return false;

   Rect elementBounds = element.TransformToVisual(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
   Rect containerBounds = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);

   return (elementBounds.Top <= element.ActualHeight && elementBounds.Bottom > containerBounds.Top);
}
```

For a completed sample please reference [this](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/blob/master/ListViewGroupDemo/ListViewGroupDemo/ListViewGroupDemo/MainPage.xaml.cs).

Comment: So, I have to iterate through all items to check if it is visible with this method?

Comment: If that so, I have a problem. Because this will fire each time user scrolls the listview. And there is a large amount of items, sometimes 3000-4000.

Comment: @user3239349, yes, this will be fired each time user scrolls. Its efficient depend on how frequently scrolling, not the amount of items. This may not be a efficiency solution and we also not recommend that. But under your scenario this may be the only way because each time the user scrolls the first visible item changed.

Comment: Well, thatnks for the answer. For now I will use use that method. But MS should make these kind of stuff more accessible to developers.